# Prevent SSL on subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, subdomain, dnsimple

I have my main app (Ruby on Rails) hosted with Heroku, DNS managed by DNSimple. It is served using SSL with a wildcard certificate. myapp.com and www.myapp.com, both work correctly.

The issue starts when I try and direct some subdomains to other services. For example I want blog.myapp.com to point to our instance of Ghost.org. I am also trying to point data.myapp.com to a different heroku app that we use for reporting purposes.

I don't need/want either of these subdomains to use SSL but it seems no matter what I try, that they try and fail to load the HTTPS version.

To be honest I'm confused where this is being triggered from. Where should I be altering the configuration. My Rails App, Heroku, DNSimple, the SSL cert, somewhere else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this issue by clearing the browser cache on my machine. 
I'm not sure what caused it to force SSL to begin with but the current configuration seems to be now be working.